# Sharepoint in Explorer-View can't display images "because the file is empty"

Tags: sharepoint-server, file, image, explorer-view

I am administrating a SQL Server 2014 for our Sharepoint 2013.
Currently users are facing the following issue:

Using the Explorer View, some images randomly (at least I can't find a pattern until now) are not displayed because "the file is empty". So I don't even see a preview / thumbnail. If I expand the files properties the image size displays 0,0 KB. Clicking a second time or copy that image to another location, sometimes makes the picture visible. Keeping the session open, later on it might happen that the same image is gone again. Out of 100 images in a folder, a couple can't be displayed at the very first attempt.

But by clicking the properties or trying to copy that file - in the end every single image is visible. So I never found an image which was really 0,00KB.

I have no Idea how this problem can be solved since I have no clue where this is coming from.

I am using Internet Explorer 11 and run Windows 7 on my machine while the server is 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2014 and Sharepoint 2013.

**EDIT 29.02.2016**
It affects all files, not only images. Also saved emails can be empty. Meaning 0,00 KB in size.

Comment: Sounds like it's something network-related to me. Do you have a record of exact moment when this happened last time? If yes, can you check IIS logs in SP servers at that moment?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I didn't check iis logs for now. Will do on Monday and report.

Comment: I think you might be right with "network related", the logs are fine

Comment: if your frontends are being load balanced, perhaps it would be a good idea to check things there. I had some caching issues in the past myself

Comment: Currently it is not load balanced, thank you for your input. It might be a caching issue, I will continue chasing it :)

Comment: My guess currently is that this problem is related to the IIS configuration of the authentication.

Comment: its surely a network related problem as per your description. Did you try using another browser? just asking as IE 11 is little buggy with sp13 sometimes

Comment: Is the WebDav role disabled/uninstalled on your SharePoint servers? Having it enabled can cause unexpected WebDav behavior in SharePoint.

Comment: sure it is, I use the file explorer view as I said. I guess this requires the webdav role. hmmm

Comment: No, SharePoint has it's own WebDav provider used for explorer view and mapping drives etc. If the Windows Server / IIS WebDav role is enabled then there can be a conflict between the two. Explorer view and drive mapping will often still work, but with unpredictable results. It should definitely be disabled.

Comment: how you open the explorer view, I mean, are you open the site in the IE then from the riboon you click open with explorer? or you mapping it or something elsse

Comment: @RayofCommand http://www.bitkinex.com/ and https://app.anyclient.com/ are nice free WebDAV clients, if they work fine, then I'd research the client side

Comment: waqas, I open the explorer view through IE as you described.

Comment: Can you please run a `Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx -Identity Database` and again for `-Identity Files`. Reproduce the issue, then use `Clear-SPLogLevel`. Grab the ULS log files (from all servers, if necessary, using `Merge-SPLogLevel`). We'll be able to better help you with these ULS logs. They'll be too long to post here, and should be in txt format. You'll want to scrub the logs of any personal information (server names, user names, etc.).

Comment: do I have to install the desktop-experience feature from the windows features? Currently it is not, I see some posts which advice to install it.